# What is the area 51 link?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, blog, area-51

What is the mysterious area 51 link on the right hand menu of the [stackoverflow blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/) for?

[area 51 image http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/5158/area51l.jpg](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/5158/area51l.jpg)

Comment: It's where they keep the c# flying saucers and jQuery aliens.  Actually, Jeff and Joel have a $100 bet as to how long it will take for someone to post a question about it on Meta.

Comment: And here I thought they were antimony. Get it? Me neither.

Comment: What happens if you click the link?

Comment: There is no href. oooooooh...

Comment: Voting to close as "you ain't seen nuthin'."

Comment: Nothing to see here, move along, move along...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the new Stack Exchange Site Proposal Tool.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52005/stack-exchange-area-51-sneak-peek

Answer (score 13):

There is no link. There is no Area 51. Move along.

[image]

**update:** The [site is now public](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52005/stack-exchange-area-51-sneak-peek).

Comment: I don't think the *phrase* "Area 51" even exists.

Comment: I Want To Believe

Comment: @Bill. What's "Area 51" why did you put it in quotes? It's not even proper English!

Answer (score 2):

Look, we have to put all the unicorns SOMEwhere for the other 364 days of the year.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I don't know what you're seeing, but I just have an icon and text -- it's not a link, it's not clickable. Thus, I'm inclined to think it's just a goof-up, or maybe even a joke.</strike>

In other words, move along, nothing to see here.

I guess the [secret's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51998/what-is-the-area-51-link/52006#52006) [out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52005/stack-exchange-area-51-sneak-peek) now. :)